# Where is this image being generated on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't figure out where the chain link image is coming from on my blogger page (http://jareds94-wine.blogspot.com). Using Google Chrome's inspect feature I can see that it has something to do with hentry::before but it's not coming from the CSS so it must be coming form a javascript file right? Any help would be much appreciate as I'm trying to change it to another image.

Comment: "This one [will be] resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers".

Comment: I understand that. Where should I go in the future for specific questions like this?

Comment: Take a look at the `Resources` tab in the Chrome dev tool/console. Might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bitmap image, but a character from the font awesome toolkit

```
.hentry:before {
    content: "\f0c1";
    z-index: 2;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Here `\f0c1` relates to the character in the font which renders as a chain link

Comment: Ah thank you, I could not figure out what the "\f0c1" was used for.

Answer (score 1):

That "Image" is actually just a glyph supplied by FontAwesome.
It is being generated by your css like so:

```
.hentry:before {
content: "\f0c1";
z-index: 2;
font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I could not figure out what the "\f0c1" was used for.